# Laravel 5.3 Different Fields Per User Role Type how to implement this using polymorphism?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

Title says it all

For example

I want the main laravel User Model to have different kinds of roles and every role

has different fields

Example

User has a role of Employee

Where that role will have different fields for the user

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use polymorphism here. `User` model used by Laravel so, you should keep all similar data in this model. Then create `Employee` and other models. Then you should add [one to one](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one) relation between `User` and all other models.

```
class User extends Model
{ 
    public function employee()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Employee');
    }
}
```

Comment: Is that the cleanest way to do that?

or i can make a multiple table inheritance for that?

Comment: @RalphChristianEclipse yes. Actually, if you have not much different data for Employee and other types of users and your app has really complicated structure, it's better to keep data in single `User` model. You don't want to have a situation when you need to use series of complicated Eloquent queries to get simple profile data. If data structure is simple, use one to one relationship.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this, using [Polymorphic Relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations) :

Table structure would be:

```
managers
  id - integer
  title - string
  body - text

employees
    id - integer
    title - string
    url - string

users
    id - integer
    body - text
    userable_id - integer
    userable_type - string

roles
    id - integer
    name - string
    description - text

role_user
    id - integer
    role_id - integer
    user_id - integer
```

And Models would be designed as:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get all of the owning userable models.
     */
    public function userable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }

    /**
     * User and Roles relationship
     */
    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Roles');
    }
}

class Employee extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get all of the employee's comments.
     */
    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('App\Employee', 'userable');
    }
}

class Manager extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get all of the manager's comments.
     */
    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('App\Manager', 'userable');
    }
}

class Role extends Model
{
    /**
     * Relationship with User and Role Models
     */
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: any ideas how can i attach that Employee model in the role table rather than the user?

i think the role table is redundant? no?

Comment: @RalphChristianEclipse - You should add roles to `users` table as this table is common for all types of users (either for Employee, Manager, etc...), the way that I am suggesting is the best way to implement user with roles!